# Как восстановить SD карту памяти после Raspberry Pi?

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, sd, diskpart, разметка-диска

Я купил microSD карту памяти на 32гб Mirex. Скачал ПО для Raspberry Pi и начал работать. Через пару дней она выдавала тупо зелёный экран с ошибками. Когда я вставил microSD в Windows, то Windows начал зависать, и просто не читал microSD. Иногда с попытки 20,  ему удавалось его прочитать. Я попытался отформатировать, ошибка, попробовал diskpart, ошибка, попробовал удалить диски, ошибка. Психанул, и через три месяца попытался снова восстановить microSD. Но теперь когда я вставляю её в Windows, он тупо зависает а потом выдаёт чёрный экран. И когда его достаю, windows снова начинает свою работу. Попробовал другие пк, ноутбуки, тоже самое. Всё просто зависает, и не хочет ничего работать.

Comment: Ну может карта просто бракованная попалась?

Comment: Нет, это происходит уже второй раз с разными картами памяти.

Comment: Ну а `gparted live` чё показывает?

Comment: я уже написал, Windows просто зависает. Но диск показывает, хоть и не открывается.

Comment: Было что-то подобное. Вставил в беззеркалку (Olympus OM-D EM1 Mark II, если конкретика важна, но, скорее всего, не важно), камера ругнулась, предложила отформатировать. Получил на выходе SD карту с ExFAT.